# Current flow between points with the same voltage (same node)

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, current, current-source

So in this circuit it's obvious that the current from the 5 A source moves from the source to up and left and the 10 A moves from the source to up to left

But what really forces the 10 A to move left, since all the upper points really have the same voltage, no potential difference, how does it choose its direction, or how does it even move if all these points have the same potential?

[image]

Comment: In real life the points DON'T have the same voltage potential.  This is just a simulation... don't take it so literally.  In real life, every wire has resistance (it may be very very small, but it DOES have resistance).  So Ohms law E=IR applies.  There will be a slight voltage drop if current is flowing in a wire.  (Assuming this is not a superconducting material of course....)   By E=IR,  Since R can not be zero, then if E=0, it means I=0  (and vice versa).  Ohms law ALWAYS works, even when you think it doesn't.....

Comment: Also (anwer below is good), current does not flow in sense of water or so. As already said, the upper and lower line technically are points. Or better Ends of a pipe. The Resistor is that pipe, filled with balls. So all the Sources "hammer" new Balls into one End of the Pipe and with each new ball pushed into the pipe, another ball pops out of the other end. This is how the current "flows"  through the resistor... even if you make the pipe longer and reessemble the 90° turns, and push new balls through 3 openings into the pipe, like in your circuit, current still would  flow through the res...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Left and right have incidental meaning on a schematic, but there's no meaning for the circuit it's describing. I'm not sure you don't have left and right mixed up anyway in your description. Fortunately, it's irrelevant.

The circuit you've drawn has two **Nodes**. The ground node at the bottom labelled 0 V, and the 400 V node at the top. Each node has zero size, the voltage at all connection points is equal. All currents enter and leave at the same point.

Each node is drawn in the schematic as a horizontal wire purely for drawing tidiness. Drawing the node as a point would be untidy but still readable with these four components, but on a schematic of typical complexity would be completely unmanageable.

There are three current sources connected between the nodes, injecting a total of 20 A into the 400 V node, and - 20 A into the GND node. The current flows through the resistor.

Answer (score 1):

Current from the 10A source has to move somewhere and the only "somewhere" is to return the current to its source is through the resistor.

Answer (score 1):

> what really forces the 10 A to move left?

It's the interaction between [Kirchoff's Current Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws#Kirchhoff%27s_current_law), and the definition of "[current source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current_source)."

The current through an ideal current source, *by definition,* must always and forever be the value on the label, flowing in the direction pointed by the arrow.

The current from the 10 A source must "move to the left" (i.e., must flow through the resistor) because there is no place else it can possibly go. The other two current sources must, by definition, move 5A each in the direction pointed by their arrows. Current from the 10A source cannot flow against those arrows. So, according to Kirchoff, that leaves the resistor as the only possible return path.